# No definition of [sensor_msgs] for OS version []

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS. Just installed Indigo on linux Mint 17 (ubuntu 14.04 based).

When going through a tutorial I run:

```
$ rosdep install joint_state_publisher
```

And get the next message:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
joint_state_publisher: Unsupported OS [mint]
```

After a little research, I tried

```
$ export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:14.04
```

But now, after the same rosdep install call I get:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
joint_state_publisher: No definition of [sensor_msgs] for OS version []
```

I am not very sure of what I should try now. I thought Ubuntu 14.04 was supported and in most similar issues people get some key inside the last brackets of the message.

I read about declaring a new OS, but Mint is already in the list of rosdep and that's getting me even more confused.  I also got to [this issue on github](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/25), which is still open and seems related.

I am lost but willing to work a lot on it, so any advice is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194527/no-definition-of-%5Bsensor_msgs%5D-for-os-version-%5B%5D/) by [RubenCabrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/20391/rubencabrera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting ROS_OS_OVERRIDE ought to be the easier solution. I would start by playing with that first.

You may need to use `export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:trusty` instead of 14.04, because ROS uses the ubuntu release names to identify Ubuntu releases.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-08**:
`rosdep` doesn't always play nice with `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE`. I think it would work if you use `--os=ubuntu:trusty`.

**Comment by [RubenCabrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/20391/rubencabrera/) on 2014-10-09**:
Thanks a lot! I tried first to run rosdep with --os=ubuntu:trusty and it worked like a charm! I then ran "export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:trusty" just in case for further use. Thanks again!